# Variable length Array tuple in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to define variable-length Array tuple?

```
["string", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
["string", 1]
```

Something like

```
type StringNumbers = [string, ...number]
```

Comment: How about `type StringNumbers = [string, ...number[]]`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir OMG, TypeScript type system would never stop surprising me, I was not expected that it's possible :). Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use rest in tuples:

```
type StringNumbers = [string, ...number[]]
```