# Function returning a variable length generic array tuple

Tags: typescript, tuples, inferred-type

Consider the following:

```
function makeOutputArrayBasedOnInputArray<T>(arrayOfStuff: T[]) {
    return arrayOfStuff.map(item => ({ item }));
}

const x = makeOutputArrayBasedOnInputArray([1, 'two']);
const y = x[0] // { item: string | number; }
const z = x[1] // { item: string | number; }
```

What I'd love is instead for the types to be surfaced:

```
const y = x[0] // { item: number; }
const z = x[1] // { item: string; }
```

So imagine the `doIt` function was returning a tuple type which is entirely generic and of varying length; driven by the input to the function.  So this would work too:

```
const x = makeOutputArrayBasedOnInputArray([7, 'nine', Date]);
const a = x[0] // { item: number; }
const b = x[1] // { item: string; }
const c = x[2] // { item: Date; }
```

Is this possible? Or have I reached the limits of `infer` and tuples?

See also: [Variable length Array tuple in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59620225/variable-length-array-tuple-in-typescript) and [Typescript, generic variadic factory function returning tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63953283/typescript-generic-variadic-factory-function-returning-tuple)

#### Update based on @A_blop's answer:

Hello and thanks for your answer!  Whilst it does answer the question, it relies on the caller using `as const`.  Without the `as const`, alas it doesn't work.

This may turn out to be key.  Some context: the question behind the question is a PR I've raised to improve the type definitions of react-query: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/pull/1527/files

The change at present looks like this:

```
export function useQueries<
  TQueryFnData = unknown,
  TError = unknown,
  TData = TQueryFnData
>(
  queries: UseQueryOptions<TQueryFnData, TError, TData>[]
): UseQueryResult<TData, TError>[] {
// ...
}
```

And this is great but has the non-specific type inference problem.  Ideally we'd like this behaviour:

```
const result = useQueries([
    { queryKey: key1, queryFn: () => 1 },
    { queryKey: key2, queryFn: () => 'two' },
])
// result[0].data => number | undefined
// result[1].data => string | undefined
```

But without requiring the caller specifying `as const` - which may not be possible?

Comment: updated answer with a variant to narrow tuples from callee side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an explicit function return type consisting of a mapped tuple type:

```
function fn<T extends readonly any[]>(arr: T): {[K in keyof T]: {item: T[K]} } {
    return arr.map(item => ({ item })) as any;
}

const x = fn([1, 'two'] as const);
// x: readonly [{ item: 1; }, { item: "two"; }]
const y = x[0] // y: { item: 1; }
const z = x[1] // z: { item: "two"; }
```

Update:
To narrow the type from the callee side, you can use variadic tuple types (TS 4.0):

```
function fn<T extends readonly any[]>(arr: [...T]): // <-- note [...T]
  {[K in keyof T]: {item: T[K]} } {...}
```

[Playground code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMMAeAKogpgDylsAEwGdEAnLAQ0IQBsBPRSsegbQF0A+ACkrLIBciVgDox6dgEohAb1YBpRDCQBrLPTjBEE2THwBbIegXsAvonMyAUIlvksUEGSR8yI-ZQAO3PVn2IAXk5EbhklAwtJSSZSZnoAbitTKysIBGIoRBxA5DBuVgBGABpEAHIoAHc4UqlEtLAMxEYArNYABnZEVPTMgC8cnELOqyA)

Comment: nice solution. I always use `keyof` for objects, but you reminded me that it useful as well for arrays